# Acro package: Handling possessive case (apostrophe s)

Tags: acronyms, acro

The current v1.5 acro package (http://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/wiki/Home, not the same as the also-popular acronym package) does not have an acronym invocation that automatically takes care of the possessive case, i.e., when the noun for which the acronym is followed immediately by an apostrophe "s".  Some web search reveals some material that might be adaptable to handle the case, e.g., http://hstuart.dk/2007/08/03/programming-latex-—-writing-commands, but adapting it to the acro package will require much more knowledge of tex programming under-the-hood than I currently have.  I realize that the knowledge can be acquired, but unfortunately, I have to make choices based on my timelines as well. This means rewording an otherwise efficiently constructed sentence to avoid apostrophe "s".

Would this be trivial for someone to adapt for the acro package?

This has been posted to:
http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=24989
[Acro package: Handling possessive case (apostrophe s)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192930/acro-package-handling-possessive-case-apostrophe-s)

Comment: As I'm no native speaker and my language has no possessive case apostrophe s: can you give an example of how long and short version should look like? Maybe a sentence containing both versions?

Comment: @cgnieder: Off-topic comment: Take a look around of wrong genitive apostrophes in German language usage ;-)

Comment: @cgnieger: Assume that there exists an organization The Awesome Group (TAG).  Assume that the 1st occurance in a document is: "The Awesome Group's (TAG's) Belly Scratching Division (BSD) is also awesome".  Note the possessive apostrophe-s.  In the same way that the acro package allows you to specify the plural (\acp{tag}), I would like to be able to specify a possessive apostrophe-s, e.g., \acas{tag} (assuming that the acronym name is "tag").

Comment: Looking forward to using it....

Comment: Could I impose upon you for a pointer as to how to get and set it up?  I browsed around the site and downloaded cgnieder-acro-93f7b10ff8a4, but it only contains the manual. I don't normally delve into LaTeX under the hood, as I found that I create incompatibilities with my MiKTeK installation when I did so in the past.  I've managed to make do with only the packages available via MiKTeK, but I can give new package updates a try if the process is clear.  Thanks.

Comment: I also initially plunked the code into a tex file and tried LaTeXing it.  It ended with:

"    ! Undefined control sequence.
    l.6 \acro_define_ending:nnn".

Looking through the log file for suspects, but my past successes in troubleshooting LaTeX files don't normally come from looking at the log file.

Answer (score 5):

### Updated Answer

Since v2.0 `acro` has a concept of *endings*. It handles the plural forms this way and allows the definition of additional endings. With `acro` v3 a new ending is declared as follows:

```
\DeclareAcroEnding{possessive}{'s}{'s}
```

This defines a command `\acropossessive` which can be used to define new `acro` commands. It also defines a number of acroynm properties and options to set the endings individually for certain acronyms or to change the defaults generally.

Here is a complete example that also shows how to define suitable commands for `acro` v3.0:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcroEnding{possessive}{'s}{'s}

\NewAcroCommand\acg{m}{\acropossessive\UseAcroTemplate{first}{#1}}
\NewAcroCommand\acsg{m}{\acropossessive\UseAcroTemplate{short}{#1}}
\NewAcroCommand\aclg{m}{\acropossessive\UseAcroTemplate{long}{#1}}

\DeclareAcronym{MP}{
  short            = MP ,
  long             = Member of Parliament ,
  long-plural-form = Members of Parliament ,
  long-possessive-form = Member's of Parliament
}

\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
  short = CD ,
  long  = compact disc
}

\begin{document}

first: \acg{cd}; \acg{MP}

short: \acsg{cd}; \acsg{MP}

long: \aclg{cd}; \aclg{MP}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Original Answer:

Since v2.0 `acro` has a concept of *endings*. It handles the plural forms this way and allows the definition of additional endings:

```
\ProvideAcroEnding{possessive}{'s}{'s}
```

This defines a lower level command `\acro_possessive:` which can be used to define new `acro` commands and defines a number of options to set the endings individually for certain acronyms.

Here is a complete example that also shows how to define suitable commands for `acro`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\ProvideAcroEnding {possessive} {'s} {'s}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewAcroCommand \acg
  {
    \acro_possessive:
    \acro_use:n {#1}
  }
\NewAcroCommand \acsg
  {
    \acro_possessive:
    \acro_short:n {#1}
  }
\NewAcroCommand \aclg
  {
    \acro_possessive:
    \acro_long:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareAcronym{MP}{
  short            = MP ,
  long             = Member of Parliament ,
  long-plural-form = Members of Parliament ,
  long-possessive-form = Member's of Parliament
}

\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
  short = CD ,
  long  = compact disc
}

\begin{document}

first: \acg{cd}; \acg{MP}

short: \acsg{cd}; \acsg{MP}

long: \aclg{cd}; \aclg{MP}

\end{document}
```

Note that several endings can't really be applied to an acronym. If we were to define

```
\NewAcroCommand \acpg
  {
    \acro_possessive:
    \acro_plural:
    \acro_use:n {#1}
  }
```

we'd get *CDs's*…