# Why does acro add the plural ending in front of the short version in addition to the end?

Tags: acro

See this minimum working example:

```
% compile with LuaLaTex and Biber

% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoption{listof}{totocnumbered,leveldown}
% unicode
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% acronyms
\usepackage{acro}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192930/acro-package-handling-possessive-case-apostrophe-s#268225
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ProvideAcroEnding{genetiv}{s}{s}
\NewAcroCommand \acg {
    \acro_genetiv:
    \acro_use:n {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\acsetup{
    hyperref = true,
    page-style = comma,
    pages = all, %/first
    % list-style = tabular
    tooltip=true,
    activate-trailing-tokens = {dash,babel-hyphen}, % German quotation for hyphen, see official doc
    cite-connect = {} % no space before citation
}

\DeclareAcronym{qrCode}{
    short = {QR-\-Code},
    long = \enquote{\foreignlanguage{english}{Quick Response}}-\-Code,
    % short-genetiv = ,
}

% deutsch
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage{lmodern} % font
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
     custom: \acg{qrCode} 

     plural: \acfp{qrCode} 

     for comparison, singular: \acf{qrCode} 
\end{document}
```

The problem is the QR code acronym, defined via the package `acro`.

It looks like this:
[image: custom: „Quick Response“-Codes (sQR-Codes); plural: „Quick Response“-Codes (sQR-Codes); for comparison, singular: „Quick Response“-Code (QR-Code)1]

Now in both the plural and the custom ("genetiv") defined word ending, the short version gets an `s` before the word (**s**QR-Codes) in addition to after the word ending.

This issue does *not* happen:

- when you only request the single version standalone (without first appearance) via `\acsp` e.g.
- or, as demonstrated, when you request the singular version.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499134/ The issue is a bug in version 2.9 of `acro`. You find workarounds at https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/120/having-an-acronym-in-plural-form-the-first

Comment: this is fixed in the newest version of `acro`. Please make an update